# C# Modelbinding custom object

Tags: c#, model-binding

I have a class that convert between physical units, based on an enum collection. In code you can switch the engineerin unit on the enum, and the object will calculate the engineering value based on the internal (SI) unit.

Now I have created an editortemplate for MVC to input a value and its engineering unit.

My problem now resides in that the ModelBinder assigns the properties in the wrong way around, the unit should be assigned before the value otherwise the internal value is calculated wrong. The internal value is calculated as soon as the engineering value is assigned.

I can create a custom model binder to assign the properties in the right order, however sometimes the same editortemplate is used several times on the same viewpage, how would I deal with that in the customer model binder?

-Edit- 
I can also make viewmodels for each of the "smart" objects, and translate them in the controller, but not sure this is appropiate, this would mean I have to create dummy objects for each physical unit, but obviously would seperate my view properly from my framework/logic

Best Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something of a design question.

I would recommend using a separate view model that doesn't depend upon assigning values in a specific order, and then mapping the values to the class you have at the controller. Pre-controller logic (action filters and model binders) step out of the controller based work flow, which is a decision that shouldn't be made lightly.

Comment: I will go with additional viewmodels then for just entering the valuse... kind of took my editortemplate to none though :(

Comment: Yup. I've found that using separate, simple classes for frameworks like MVC avoids subtle problems like these.